# Conditions under which the Lattice Generated by a Subset of Lattice Vectors is Equivalent to the Original Lattice

Tags: integer-lattices

In general, the sublattice $L_2$ generated by subset of vectors of $L_1$ need not have the same rank as $L_1$.  Even if it does, it may be a proper sublattice of $L_1$.  However, if the rank and determinant of $L_2$ matches those of $L_1$, then is it possible to conclude that $L_2 = L_1$?  If not, what are the minimal necessary conditions on the subset?  Clearly, if the subset includes a basis of $L_1$, it's sufficient, but I'm looking for conditions which are easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

*sigh* $\;$ Answered my own question again.  If the rank and determinants are equal, then the index of $L_2$ in $L_1$ is 1, *i.e.* they're the same lattice, perhaps with a different choice of basis.  [This page](http://www.mathreference.com/la-lat,cov.html#:%7E:text=The%20index%20of%20a%20sublattice,cells%20may%20not%20pack%20perfectly.) has more details.